# Highstock Axis error on spacingBottom = 0

Tags: highcharts

Highstock example: https://jsfiddle.net/1qz43heo/1/

```
spacingBottom: 0
```

Problem: When I add "spacingBottom: 0" the Y axis changes  and the lines do not "fill out" the whole space anymore!? Why?

*(spacingBottom when not set is 15: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.spacingBottom)*

[image]

Comment: Hi @DavidDunham, I have checked your example and I do not see any differences between the charts. Could you check the demo again?

Comment: Checked. Looks exactly like my screenshot. The difference is marked by red arrows here above

Comment: Ok, I have reproduced the issue with bigger `spacingBottom`: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8btr40no/, but I still don't understand the problem. Since the plot area is higher, yAxis labels may render differently. If you want to keep it constant use `tickPositions`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions or `min` and `max` properties.